# I already have a static website on gitlab can I deploy it on an azure statis web app using azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-web-app-service, cicd

I don't want to clone my Gitlab repository to Azure DevOps I want to use my current **Gitlab repository** and deployed it on Azure DevOps

I tried with the classic editor but there are no options to enter a build script or a default template for that FYI my application is in react

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to clone your Gitlab Repository in azure DevOps and want to use it directly. You can make use of this [**Gitlab extension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183087/how-do-i-use-gitlab-code-project-in-azure-devops) according to this SO thread answer by Vito Liu.

I added this Gitlab extension to my Azure devOps project like below:-

Visit the **Gitab extension link above** click on **Get it Free** and **Download it in your Azure DevOps project** like below:-

[image]

Now, Create one Service Connection with your Gitlab Username and Token like below:-

[image]

Create Access token in your Gitlab User settings like below:-

[image]

Add the ***Username and Access Token in the New Gitlab service connection*** like below:-

[image]

Now in your ***Release Pipeline > Artifacts > Add > Select Gitlab > Gitlab Service Connection > Gitlab Repository which contains your Static web app > Add.***

[image]

Now, **I created Azure Static Web app and copied Deployment Token** like below:-

[image]

[image]

**Select Static Web App task and fill your static web app and API location like below:-**

[image]

**Add API Token like below:-**

[image]

Save your pipeline and Create your Release pipeline for Deployment.